# Logout from next-auth with keycloak provider not works

Tags: reactjs, next.js, single-sign-on, keycloak, next-auth

I have a nextjs application with next-auth to manage the authentication.

Here my configuration

```
....
export default NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    KeycloakProvider({
      id: 'my-keycloack-2',
      name: 'my-keycloack-2',
      clientId: process.env.NEXTAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
      issuer: process.env.NEXTAUTH_CLIENT_ISSUER,
      profile: (profile) => ({
        ...profile,
        id: profile.sub
      })
    })
  ],
....
```

Authentication works as expected, but when i try to logout using the next-auth signOut function it doesn't works. Next-auth session is destroyed but keycloak mantain his session.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some research i found a reddit conversation https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/redv1r/nextauth_signout_does_not_end_keycloak_session/ that describe the same problem.

Here my solution.

I write a custom function to logout

```
  const logout = async (): Promise<void> => {
    const {
      data: { path }
    } = await axios.get('/api/auth/logout');
    await signOut({ redirect: false });
    window.location.href = path;
  };
```

And i define an api path to obtain the path to destroy the session on keycloak `/api/auth/logout`

```
export default (req, res) => {
  const path = `${process.env.NEXTAUTH_CLIENT_ISSUER}/protocol/openid-connect/logout? 
                redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL)}`;

  res.status(200).json({ path });
};
```

**UPDATE**

In the latest versions of keycloak (at time of this post update is 19.*.* -> https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/main/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/logout.adoc) the redirect uri becomes a bit more complex

```
export default (req, res) => {

  const session = await getSession({ req });

  let path = `${process.env.NEXTAUTH_CLIENT_ISSUER}/protocol/openid-connect/logout? 
                post_logout_redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL)}`;

if(session?.id_token) {
  path = path + `&id_token_hint=${session.id_token}`
} else {
  path = path + `&client_id=${process.env.NEXTAUTH_CLIENT_ID}`
}

  res.status(200).json({ path });
};
```

> Note that you need to include either the client_id or id_token_hint parameter in case that post_logout_redirect_uri is included.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I found that after clicking on the logout button in Keycloak, the page doesn't redirect to my app login page. Am I missing any configuration from Keycloak?

Comment: How to sign out same user from all devices if he logged in to multiple devices since next auth set cookies?

Answer (score 11):

I've got the same problem, but instead of creating another route, I extended signOut event to make necessery request for keycloak:

```
import NextAuth, { type AuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import KeycloakProvider, { type KeycloakProfile } from "next-auth/providers/keycloak"
import { type JWT } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { type OAuthConfig } from "next-auth/providers";


declare module 'next-auth/jwt' {
  interface JWT {
    id_token?: string;
    provider?: string;
  }
}


export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    KeycloakProvider({
      clientId: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID || "keycloak_client_id",
      clientSecret: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET || "keycloak_client_secret",
      issuer: process.env.KEYCLOAK_ISSUER || "keycloak_url",
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      if (account) {
        token.id_token = account.id_token
        token.provider = account.provider
      }
      return token
    },
  },
  events: {
    async signOut({ token }: { token: JWT }) {
      if (token.provider === "keycloak") {
        const issuerUrl = (authOptions.providers.find(p => p.id === "keycloak") as OAuthConfig<KeycloakProfile>).options!.issuer!
        const logOutUrl = new URL(`${issuerUrl}/protocol/openid-connect/logout`)
        logOutUrl.searchParams.set("id_token_hint", token.id_token!)
        await fetch(logOutUrl);
      }
    },
  }
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

And, because `id_token_hint` is provided in request, users don't need to click logOut twice.

Comment: what if the logout API call that you are making in events fails (for some unknown reason)? your user will be logged out from UI but not from keycloak (can be a security vulnerability)

Answer (score 5):

So, I had a slightly different approach building upon this thread here.

I didn't really like all the redirects happening in my application, nor did I like adding a new endpoint to my application just for dealing with the "post-logout handshake"

Instead, I added the `id_token` directly into the initial JWT token generated, then attached a method called `doFinalSignoutHandshake` to the `events.signOut` which automatically performs a `GET` request to the keycloak service endpoint and terminates the session on behalf of the user.

This technique allows me to maintain all of the current flows in the application and still use the standard `signOut` method exposed by `next-auth` without any special customizations on the front-end.

This is written in typescript, so I extended the `JWT` definition to include the new values (shouldn't be necessary in vanilla JS

```
// exists under /types/next-auth.d.ts in your project
// Typescript will merge the definitions in most
// editors
declare module "next-auth/jwt" {
    interface JWT {
        provider: string;
        id_token: string;
    }
}
```

Following is my implementation of `/pages/api/[...nextauth.ts]`

```
import axios, { AxiosError } from "axios";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { JWT } from "next-auth/jwt";
import KeycloakProvider from "next-auth/providers/keycloak";

// I defined this outside of the initial setup so
// that I wouldn't need to keep copying the
// process.env.KEYCLOAK_* values everywhere
const keycloak = KeycloakProvider({
    clientId: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET,
    issuer: process.env.KEYCLOAK_ISSUER,
});

// this performs the final handshake for the keycloak
// provider, the way it's written could also potentially
// perform the action for other providers as well
async function doFinalSignoutHandshake(jwt: JWT) {
    const { provider, id_token } = jwt;

    if (provider == keycloak.id) {
        try {
            // Add the id_token_hint to the query string
            const params = new URLSearchParams();
            params.append('id_token_hint', id_token);
            const { status, statusText } = await axios.get(`${keycloak.options.issuer}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?${params.toString()}`);

            // The response body should contain a confirmation that the user has been logged out
            console.log("Completed post-logout handshake", status, statusText);
        }
        catch (e: any) {
            console.error("Unable to perform post-logout handshake", (e as AxiosError)?.code || e)
        }
    }
}

export default NextAuth({
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    providers: [
        keycloak
    ],
    callbacks: {
        jwt: async ({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) => {
            if (account) {
                // copy the expiry from the original keycloak token
                // overrides the settings in NextAuth.session
                token.exp = account.expires_at;
                token.id_token = account.id_token;
                //20230822 - updated to include the "provider" property
                token.provider = account.provider;
            }

            return token;
        }
    },
    events: {
        signOut: ({ session, token }) => doFinalSignoutHandshake(token)
    }
});
```

Comment: What does token.exp mean? JWT in next-auth does not have this property, at least the latest version.

Comment: This didn't work for me until I added the following to the jwt callback: `token.provider = account.provider`

Comment: `token.exp` is a standard `JWT` property signifying the token's expiration date.

Comment: You can probably omit the provider check if you're only using keycloak to authenticate and not accepting other authentication methods

Answer (score -2):

`signOut` [only clears session cookies](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/4612#issuecomment-1160202736) without destroying user's session on the provider.

1. hit `GET` `/logout` endpoint of the provider to destroy user's session
2. do `signOut()` to clear session cookies, **only if step 1 was successful**

---

**Implementation**:
*Assumption*: you are storing user's `idToken` in the session object returned by `session` callback

1. create an idempotent endpoint (PUT) on server side to make this GET call to the provider
   **create file:** `pages/api/auth/signoutprovider.js`

```js
import { authOptions } from "./[...nextauth]";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";

export default async function signOutProvider(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "PUT") {
    const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);
    if (session?.idToken) {
      try {
        // destroy user's session on the provider
        await axios.get("<your-issuer>/protocol/openid-connect/logout", { params: id_token_hint: session.idToken });
        res.status(200).json(null);
      }
      catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(null);
      }
    } else {  
      // if user is not signed in, give 200
      res.status(200).json(null);
    }
  }
}
```

2. wrap `signOut` by a function, use this function to sign a user out throughout your app

```js
import { signOut } from "next-auth/react";

export async function theRealSignOut(args) {
  try {
    await axios.put("/api/auth/signoutprovider", null);
    // signOut only if PUT was successful
    return await signOut(args);
  } catch (error) {
    // <show some notification to user asking to retry signout>
    throw error;
  }
}
```

**Note**: `theRealSignOut` can be used [on client side only](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#signout) as it is using `signOut` internally.

Keycloak docs [logout](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#logout)

Comment: alternatively one can also use `getToken( { req } )` instead of `getServerSession` to get `token?.idToken`