# Next-Auth keeps own session when Keycloak session logged out

Tags: reactjs, next.js, single-sign-on, keycloak, next-auth

I have a nextjs application with next-auth to manage the Keycloak authentication.
Here is how I configured it

```
const keycloak = KeycloakProvider({
    clientId: process.env.KEYCLOAK_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.KEYCLOAK_SECRET,
    issuer: process.env.KEYCLOAK_ISSUER,
});

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    providers: [
        keycloak
    ],
    callbacks: {
        jwt: async({ token, account }) => {/*Extra logic for sign-out keycloak session*/}
    },
    events: {
        signOut: async({ token }) => {/*Extra logic for sign-out keycloak session*/}
    },
}
```

I can successfully log-in and log-out (with some tweaks for keycloak).

**The problem:** When I drop Keycloak session from it's admin panel, Next-auth does not check that and keeps it's own session. Once API service tries to verify that token from Keycloak, verification fails because session was dropped. But Next-auth keeps own session as valid.

Any ideas how to force next-auth to check if Keycloak session is still valid or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to control this with tokens rotation

https://authjs.dev/guides/basics/refresh-token-rotation

One more link with the solution specific to Keycloak, just to check if anything goes wrong

https://gist.github.com/degitgitagitya/db5c4385fc549f317eac64d8e5702f74

I have also taken `id_token` when authenticated and reuse it when refresh token. `id_token` is needed to do `Sign-out`. I've used this solution, triggering additional keycloak sign-out in events:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75178127/7147231

Comment: thank you for pointing out to the solutions you used, works great!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
    async function handleLogout() {
//    signOut('keycloak');
    await signOut({
      callbackUrl: "/api/auth/logout",
    });
  }
```

in /pages/api/auth/logout.ts

```
export default (req, res) => {
    const logOutUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_KEYCLOAK_DOMAIN + "/realms/" + process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REALM + "/protocol/openid-connect/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=" + process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WEB_URL
+ "&client_id=" + process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENTID

    res.redirect(logOutUrl);
  };
```

this solution is from https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/redv1r/nextauth_signout_does_not_end_keycloak_session/ - credit to doombubbles