# How to correctly set up Next-Auth with Keycloak

Tags: next.js, keycloak, next-auth

I am using the Next-Auth package to help with authentication in my Nextjs/Keycloak application. I followed the setup guide and got to the point where I can successfully sign in through keycloak. I click on sign in, it redirects to the keycloak login page, after filling in the details in redirects back to my site. I can see that a new session has been created in the browser as well as in keycloak.

I have, however, been struggling to understand how to "manage" the sessions after the initial login as well as how to configure the sessions in general. After the initial sign in there is a clear disconnect between the browser session and the keycloak session. For example when i would sign out in my browser, the browser session would be cleared, but not the keycloak session. I have tried to fix this by calling the keycloak logout api endpoint in the nexth auth sign out event, but this only works if i actually click on the signout button. If the session expires naturally (i put the session max age on 60 seconds to test), then the browser session gets cleared but again the keycloak session is still there.

I also dont really understand how refresh tokens are suppose to work, since after the initial login, keycloak is never "contacted" again to keep the browser session and keycloak session in sync. I also struggle to understand how will changing the keycloak session settings (Session Idle, Session Max) influence next-auth?

What i want is for my users to be able to log in. They need to be signed out if they are **inactive** for 3 hours, but they also need to be hard locked out after 1 day no matter what. Can this be done with next-auth and keycloak? And can i create a consistent connection between the two to always stay in sync? Or am I just overthinking.

Thanks

Comment: In case you're still wondering, there is an answer there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71872587/logout-from-next-auth-with-keycloak-provider-not-works

Comment: Hi I have the same problem with keycloak session. In my case i see in keycloak manager, tha session is terminated but when i try login again, the session isn't terminated.
I'm trying refresh the browser completely to initiate a new login.
I`m searching for a better solution.